# C++ member function pointer compile error

Tags: c++, polymorphism, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

This is similar to [Member function pointer cast, from Derived to Base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845481/member-function-pointer-cast-from-derived-to-base-class?rq=1) But not EXACTLY the same.  Plus, I posted an answer here, despite the multiple posts on the similar question which said it's "not possible".

I have a class constructor which takes a pointer an object and to a member function of that object's class.  It will call back into that object.

```
typedef QByteArray(QObject::*PollerClientFetchFunc)(void);

class FunctionPoller
{
public:
    FunctionPoller( QObject *client,
                    PollerClientFetchFunc clientFunc ){} 
};
```

I have another class where the functional code will be defined:

```
class SomeClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SomeClass(){}   

    QByteArray poll();
};
```

And I have a derived class from the one doing the call back:

```
class MyPoller : public FunctionPoller
{
public:
    MyPoller( SomeClass *someClass );
    ~MyPoller();

    SomeClass *someClass_;
};

MyPoller::MyPoller( SomeClass *someClass )
    : FunctionPoller( someClass, &SomeClass::poll )
    , someClass_( someClass )
{}
```

This code fails in the MyPoller constructor. The arguments passed to the super class are not kosher. That is the line `: FunctionPoller( someClass, &SomeClass::poll )` Here's the error:

> no known conversion for argument 2 from 'QByteArray (SomeClass::*)()'
>   to 'PollerClientFetchFunc {aka QByteArray (QObject::*)()}'

In a nutshell, it seems like it can't convert `SomeClass` to `QObject` in this context even though it's a decedent of it.   What's wrong here?

Comment: "In a nutshell, it seems like it can't convert SomeClass to QObject.." No, the first argument is okay, the error is for the second one.

Comment: Wait, what? If that's the case this is going over my head somehow.  What's the second argument then?

Comment: It's the function pointer that's the problem and converting the owner class of that, no? That's what I was trying to say.  The pointer to the object is fine.

Comment: Yep. The owner class must be the base class, as you specified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot cast "member pointer to derived class" to "member pointer to base class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156381/cannot-cast-member-pointer-to-derived-class-to-member-pointer-to-base-class)

Comment: poll() is not a member of QObject.  I also tried changing the code so  the parent and child did share such a function name, but that gave me the same error. Plus, it really flies in the face of what I'm actually trying to do.  I want to have a call back into a function of an any object derived from QObject (new functions tacked on on the fly).

Comment: I figured it out.  Answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  Sometimes one just needs to post a question to finally arrive at the answer!  The solution is to just explicitly cast the function pointer.

```
 : FunctionPoller( someClass, (PollerClientFetchFunc) &SomeClass::poll )
```